# Case statement to check if any record is returned by the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

My stored procedure takes [PhaseId] as the parameter, i need to return the result set from the table based on that PhaseId which is passed as the parameter.

If there is no data in the table matching that conditions then i want to return the resultset of another PhaseId, lets call it is DefaultPhaseId

```
DECLARE @DefaultPhaseId INT
SELECT @DefaultPhaseId = [PhaseId] FROM dbo.[Phase] WHERE [Description] = 'Unanimous'

SELECT * FROM [PhaseSelection] WHERE PhaseId = @PhaseId AND [IsActive] = 1
```

Here i need to check if there is any record returned by the above query, if not i need to execute the below query

```
SELECT * FROM [PhaseSelection] WHERE PhaseId = @DefaultPhaseId AND [IsActive] = 1
```

Comment: A `CASE` statement won't help you here, T-SQL doesn't support them. You could, however, use a `IF` statement though and check the value of `@@ROWCOUNT` is greater than `0`.

Comment: Tried CASE statement and that was not working, i felt may be i am not doing it in a right way so posted it  here... IF statement and @@ROWCOUNT do i need to use the query in If Statement ?

Comment: Is `PhaseId` the primary (or unique) key for the table?

Comment: *"Tried CASE statement and that was not working"* No, it won't, as I mentioned T-SQL doesn't support `Case` statements, only `CASE` expressions. And no, `@@ROWCOUNT` returns the number of rows effected from the last statement.

Comment: yes [PhaseId] is PK of [Phase] table

Comment: @Larnu can u help with sample query as i am still clueless with the @@ROWCOUNT approach

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any procedural code at all for this. You can use `UNION ALL` to add the result for the default ID, if the result for the other ID is empty.

```
SELECT *
       FROM [PhaseSelection]
       WHERE [PhaseId] = @PhaseId
             AND [IsActive] = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
       FROM [PhaseSelection]
       WHERE [PhaseId] = @DefaultPhaseId
             AND [IsActive] = 1
             AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                    FROM [PhaseSelection]
                                    WHERE [PhaseId] = @PhaseId
                                          AND [IsActive] = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play some tricks with `TOP (1) WITH TIES` this will only give you the first set of rows available.

```sql
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
    *
FROM (
    SELECT ps.*, 0 AS Ordering
        FROM [PhaseSelection] ps
        WHERE PhaseId = @PhaseId AND [IsActive] = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ps.*, 1 AS Ordering
        FROM [PhaseSelection] ps
        JOIN dbo.[Phase] p ON ps.[PhaseId] = p.[PhaseId]
        WHERE p.[IsActive] = 1 AND p.[Description] = 'Unanimous'
) ps
ORDER BY Ordering;
```